# Is is possible to target the iPhone using Apache Ant?

Tags: iphone, ant

Is it possible to build an iPhone application using Apache Ant?

Comment: @BoltClock: Jeopardy fail. You have to answer with an question!

Comment: @JustSid: [Aw, shucks.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvUZijEuNDQ)

Answer (score 1):

In principle it should be possible, but I have never really seen anyone do that. People usually just use XCode!

Comment: Thanks Yuji,                                                                 Could you please tell me the way (code), how can is possible, Because My Project manager told do like that.we are working same app on both device(iphone , andriod), they want we create both app build( andriod , iphone ) through ant apache.  please tell me , if you know

Comment: I don't think you can really share codes between android and iphone app, except for the graphic, sound, or database resources. So I don't really think it makes sense to manage codes using the same system. If your project manager really insists, you can call `xcodebuild` command line tool from `ant`. For `xcodebuild`, see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html

Comment: Your keyboard seems to be broken.

Comment: @JeremyP - Read the edits on the question to understand the punctuation here.